# How to write data from select sql into a file.sql to backup and import?

Tags: php, mysql

I write some sqls to select data from some tables with condition. So, I want to write that data to a file type .sql.zip for import when the user want to restore the data.

Example:

```
select * from table A;
select * from table B;
```

And write the data into a file.sql.zip as below:

```
insert into A (column_1, column_2, column3) values
(1,2,3),
(11,22,33),
(33,44,55);

insert into B (column_1, column_2) values
(1,2),
(11,22),
(111,222);
```

How to do that?
Thank & best regards,
BienHV

Comment: Research mysql backup and restore.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/backup-and-recovery.html come back if you have a specific problem with this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Docco Labs' [application](http://www.doccolabs.com/products_sqltablezip.html) to do specifically this.

It's called SQL Query Zipper and allows you to run a query through the DB which then outputs the data from the query into a zipped file format.